# CMake : target_compile_options() vs target_compile_definitions()

Tags: cmake

What is the different between `target_compile_options()` vs `target_compile_definitions()`?

As per CMake docs:

`target_compile_options` - Adds options to the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` or `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` target properties.

`target_compile_definitions` - The `INTERFACE`, `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE` keywords are required to specify the scope of the following arguments. `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC` items will populate the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property of `<target>`. `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` items will populate the `INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property of `<target>`.

But I am not getting which one to use and when.

Comment: Everything is in their names: use one for compile options and the other for definitions.

Comment: Silly question but when to use compile options and when to use definitions?

Comment: from my observation, we can use target_compile_options() in place of  target_compile_definitions() but not vice versa.

Comment: Read what compiler options are, those will be your `*_compile_options()`, then read what C++ macros are—they are your `*_compile_definitions()`

Comment: I am able to use macro with target_compile_options(). I set target_compile_options(myapplication
        PRIVATE
        -DABCDE)
and in my cpp file - #ifdef ABCDE
 cout<<"hello";
#endif

hello is being printed. seems like macro ABCDE is defined

Comment: It is not about what you are able to do, it is about what you are supposed to do. You are not supposed to put macros in `*_compile_options`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `target_compile_definitions` for definitions of preprocessor macros, use `target_compile_options` for other flags.

For `target_compile_definitions` cmake is able to choose the appropriate compiler flags based on the compiler used. Furthermore you save yourself the `-D`:

**Example**

```
target_compile_definitions(MyTarget PRIVATE
    ADD_DEBUG_PRINTS=1
    ABCDE
)

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    target_compile_options(MyTarget PRIVATE -Wall)
endif()
```

Note that the use of `-Wall` usually shouldn't be added in this place; it's just used as an example of a well known compiler flag...

Comment: _"the use of -Wall usually shouldn't be added in this place"_ Why? In what place it should be added?

Comment: @ixSci If activated for the whole project, it should go into the toolchain file; alternatively there should be a cache variable that optionally allows choosing, if the option is enabled. For the second option a custom package containing functions/macros for applying this kind of option would be preferable; this results in `CMakeLists.txt` files that are shorter and therefore easier to understand...

Comment: Geez, now I understand why so many new people hate CMake, I'd also have hated it if encountered such an overcomplicated mess when I started. What you described is complex and I don't understand how it makes anything easier. What you posted in your answer is a pretty good answer for 99% projects out there. Besides, `-Wall` is not just a flag, it is a policy for the project which you shall never turn off.

Comment: @ixSci Would you consider `find_package(BuildHelpers REQUIRED COMPONENTS Warnings) ... build_helper_enable_warnings(MyTarget)` more readable or `if(<compiler1 check>) <apply compiler 1 flags>elseif(<compiler 2 check>) <apply compiler 2 flags> elseif ... endif()` more readable? What about reuseablility? For simple projects that only need to work with a compiler, the second alternative may be ok, but for larger projects with logic that needs to be reused, it's not a good alternative. Writing C++ code you create a function for logic that is reused, so treat cmake any different in this regard?

Comment: The second one. The first one is misleading because it creates an illusion of creating a dependency where there isn't any (`find_package` *is* for finding packages, external to the project). With the second approach I have every option of every compiler at a glance within ~20 lines for everything. And don't compare programming language with full IDE support with CMake, they are different and have different goals. It just happens that CMake has some capabilities of a programming language but using it as one is a big mistake.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I have nothing against using CMake capabilities where required, that includes functions and macros. I just don't like when people overuse them. That includes the method you described which was presented by some random guy on some random conference after which some people who needed at least some guidance started to believe that it is _the way_.  But no, it isn't. It is just a way which might work for some projects and fail miserably for others. It is good to know this method but blindly apply it to every project isn't.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and then I look up the offical manual in [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html). And in the bottom I see the sentence in *see Also*:

> This command can be used to add any options. However, for adding preprocessor definitions and include directories it is recommended to use the more specific commands target_compile_definitions() and target_include_directories().

So, I think it is just a statment:

- when you want to add a preprocessor flag, the recommend to use`target_compile_definitions()`, but you use `target_compile_options` is also not error.